# MIPS / PCSPIM PROGRAM : Input 3 numbers and output highest no -> lowest no

Tags: mips, pcspim

I am relatively new to MIPS programming. I am looking for a program to Input 3 numbers from the user, and output them to the screen in order from highest to lowest.

Comment: Is this a homework or what?

Comment: Yes, it's the final program of a set of 5. Got the first four fine

Comment: `$a0` is `argc`, `$a1` is `argv` in `spim`